# Laravel 5.5 PHPunit Test - "A facade root has not been set."

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, facade, laravel-5.5

When I do a try/catch on the `DB::Connection()->getPdo();`, I get the error **A facade root has not been set.** I believe it was happening with the `Schema` facades too before I tried adding the try/catch. The tests directory is, of course, outside of the app directory, and I have a feeling it has something to do with that, but I have not succeeded in figuring it out.

Here is the test class where this is happening:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Models;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\Discussion;
use App\User;
use Business\Database\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Tests\TestCase;

class DiscussionModelTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * Create the tables this model needs for testing.
     */
    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        try {
            DB::connection()->getPdo();
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

        Schema::create('discussions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });

        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a little concerning that you're building a schema inside your unit test. Usually you want to have a database pre-built and then use the `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions` trait to make sure things are backed out when the unit test completes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The thing is you cannot do this in setUpBeforeClass, because many things are run in `setUp` method. If you look at [this order of run](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html#fixtures.examples.TemplateMethodsTest.php) you will see `setUpBeforeClass` is run before `setUp` method and TestCase class is doing many things in the `setUp` method. It looks like this:

```
protected function setUp()
{
    if (! $this->app) {
        $this->refreshApplication();
    }

    $this->setUpTraits();

    foreach ($this->afterApplicationCreatedCallbacks as $callback) {
        call_user_func($callback);
    }

    Facade::clearResolvedInstances();

    Model::setEventDispatcher($this->app['events']);

    $this->setUpHasRun = true;
}
```

So what you should do is creating own `setUp` and `tearDown` methods with your own implementation like this:

```
protected function setUp()
{
   parent::setUp();
   // your code goes here
}

protected function tearDown()
{
   parent::tearDown();
   // your code goes here
}
```

Comment: I looked into the base test's setUp function and it's actually an empty function.

Comment: @JustinAnthony Have you looked at `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase` class? In this class you have `setUp` method with the content I showed

Comment: Woops, I went into that Foundation's parent setUp. Went too deep. It actually looks like that did it, putting my Schema calls into `setUp` instead of `setUpBeforeClass`. In the interim, I did find another solution using `Capsule` as well. Between the 2 methods, do you have an opinion of which is better to use?

Comment: I've never heard of capsules. I'm using setUp for such things but usually there is no point to create tables manually because you use database traits normally to create database schema from migrations.

Comment: I ran into an issue where we are using a newer version of mySQL where we use json column types, which isn't compatible with sqlite, so I need to make a sub-set of migration tailored specifically for testing. I wanted to make it so I created tables only once per test suite, but seeded them before each test begins. Does having to run faux migrations in setUp cause any significant delays in test time?

Comment: Just test it and you will see

Answer (score 10):

[I get answer here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/unit-tests-runtimeexception-a-facade-root-has-not-been-set?page=1&replyId=684813)

You shouldn’t, because a feature test would extend the TestCase class in your tests directory instead PHPUnit’s.

Remove:

```php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
```

And replace it with:

```php
use Tests\TestCase;
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who is curious as to the other method I found to work using Capsule, here is the code. this will work in both `setUpBeforeClass()` and `setUp()`. This could and should be more abstract, but this is the gist of it.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

class DiscussionModelTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * Create the tables this model needs for testing.
     */
    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        $capsule = new Capsule;

        $capsule->addConnection([
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => ':memory:',
            'prefix' => '',
        ]);

        $capsule->setAsGlobal();

        $capsule->bootEloquent();

        Capsule::schema()->create('discussions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });

        Capsule::schema()->create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id');
        });

        // Seed the faux DB
        Model::unguard();

        User::create([
            'id' => 13
        ]);

        Discussion::create([
            'id' => 5,
            'user_id' => 13
        ]);
    }
}
```