# Unable to use facades during tests on Lumen

Tags: php, phpunit, lumen, laravel-facade

I wanted to refresh my testing database once per class instead of per test using the `setUpBeforeClass` method. As it is static, I can't call `$this->artisan()` therefore I tried to use `Artisan::call()` with facades.

The problem is that facades are not working here. I receive the error `A facade root has not been set.` even though I uncommented `$app->withFacades();` from `bootstrap/app.php`.

How can I call an artisan command inside `setUpBeforeClass`?

Here is my test class:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public static function setUpBeforeClass(): void
    {
        parent::setUpBeforeClass();

        Artisan::call('migrate:fresh');
        Artisan::call('db:seed --no-interaction');
    }

    public function testOne()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible to call an artisan command in `setUpBeforeClass`. Interesting question thought, how did you came to a different conclusion?

Comment: I didn't came to a different solution. I was hopping that there was a way to call a artisan command once per file but apparently in `setUpBeforeClass` it is not possible - just saw this answer and it makes sense - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46453228/6453726. Don't know how this could be achieve but I believe it would be very useful. I posted this as an `Idea` in the Laravel repository - https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/37980

Thanks.

Comment: That sounds reasonable to me nad I've taken a quick look at the post to the idea forum. You perhaps could edit in a little bit of the code to your post there so that its more clear what you're after without the need to leave the discussion there (e.g. the `setUpBeforeClass` methods code).

Comment: Good idea. I updated the text. If you can and wan't to, please up vote the idea in GitHub. Thank you.

Comment: @guizo you should be using the trait [`DatabaseMigrations`](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/8.x/src/Testing/DatabaseMigrations.php) same as `Laravel`... But this will only run `migrate:fresh`. For `db:seed`, you should either run that on `setUp` or create a method that will call for that when you begin the test...